# Prevent Wordpress from applying magic quotes to CI cookie without changing core file

Tags: php, wordpress

**Our Problem:** We have a CodeIgniter app within the Wordpress directory and are using Wordpress' functions to generate the navigation. However, we found that Wordpress renders the Codeigniter Cookie useless due to the `wp_magic_quotes` function located in wp-includes/load.php  -- specifically this line:

```
$_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
```

Our current solution is to modify the `wp_magic_quotes` function directly using `array_walk` to loop over the `$_COOKIE` variable and apply `add_magic_quotes` to all keys except for our CI session like so:

```
function ci_ignore_magic_quotes($value,$key)
{
    if($key != "ci_session")
    {
        stripslashes_deep($value);
    }
}
```

**and changing the aforementioned line in `wp_magic_quotes` to:**

```
    array_walk($_COOKIE, 'ci_ignore_magic_quotes');
//$_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
```

However, this is obviously problematic because these changes will be discarded with the next WP upgrade.

Is it possible to address our problem this without modifying this core file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit those functions-- `wp_magic_quotes` and `wp_unregister_GLOBALS`-- without editing the core file.

This is basic PHP. You cannot redefine a function. Trying to define, or redefine, that function anywhere other than in that core file will result in an error because whatever you do, other than edit the core file, it will be defined twice in the code.

Nor are there hooks in those functions that might help you. Sorry. Three may be ways to do what you want if you explained what you want to accomplish instead of asking how to do implement some particular solution. You may have an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the x/y problem; edited accordingly.  Hopefully the revised question is more helpful.